# refernceing a class from it's object in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

i know it may be weird, but let me explain

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment = models.TextField()
    target_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')
    second_level_comment = GenericRelation(Comment, content_type_field='target_ct', object_id_field='target_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment[:40]
```

in the code above I have  a generic relation from django  and I want to reference to the comment from a comment
I can make it using filter as it's working 
but i can't find a solution to put GenericRelation field with a reference to the  comment class itself.
I want something like `self.__class__`   which here doesn't make any sense of course

Comment: there are some typing mistakes which i didn't realize, if any one can edit the question, please correct them

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would like to use this method/property in code?

Comment: thanks, i have found that the other question is already like mine